# Jquery: How to load a specific iframe from multiple iframes with same class name

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe

I have a simple html page and it has multiple button when you click on it, iframe will load from jquery script.

My function is working but I want to load a specific iframe on which I click nut it loads all the iframes.

Here is my snippet.

Html (list of buttons)

```
  <div id="mydiv">
         <iframe class="frame"  width="100%" height="300">
         </iframe>
  </div>
     <button class="button">Load</button>


  <div id="mydiv">
        <iframe class="frame"  width="100%" height="300">
        </iframe>
  </div>
    <button class="button">Load</button>
```

Css (to hide my iframes)

```
    <style>
        iframe{
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
```

Script (jquery fucntion which runs on click to load and show iframe)

```
    $(".button").click(function () {
    $(".frame").attr("src", "https://www.bing.com/");
    $('iframe').css('display', 'block');
    });
```

Please help me community.

Comment: you'll need something unique - like an ID ... of course, your ID's aren't unique, so you'll need to fix that if you want to write proper HTML

Comment: but bro the thing is if i use id and if there are 300 iframes then i need to write 300 functions it increase redundancy.

Comment: I want to do this with a single function

Comment: regardless ... non-unique id's is invalid HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to scope the code to update the correct iframe element instead of all of them. You can do something like:

```
$(".button").click(function () {
    var currentIframe = $(this).prev().find("iframe");
    currentIframe.attr("src", "https://www.bing.com/");
    currentIframe.css('display', 'block');
});
```

Comment: let me try it brother

Comment: Awesome brother its working. bro i could have use ids but i want to use one fucntion to handle 100s of iframe. brother love you really appreciate it

Comment: Brother I want to add you on linkedin please send me the link. and want to be in your circle

Comment: ohhhh so please sister can i have you linkedin?

Comment: one thing more i am using anchor tag for the same thing but when i click on anchor tag iframe not opening

Comment: here it anchor tage 

<a class="button" href="https://www.alexa.com/" style="text-decoration: none; color: inherit;" target="_blank">
        <h1><b style="text-transform: uppercase; text-align: center">IL SEGRETO REDDITIZIO PER
                GUADAGNARE SOLDI, CHE VIENE CELATO DALLE GRANDI BANCHE</b></h1>
    </a>